# Memory issues under ARC (app crashing with small leak and 2MB of allocations)

Tags: ios, memory

So I'm trying to get my first app ready to submit to the app store, and I'm at the profiling/analysis stage of it. My app is crashing, and I have some questions I can't seem to dig up answers to.

I've been running my app through Instruments checking allocations and leaks, and it's been crashing fairly regularly. The weird part is that allocations says my total is only 2-3MB, and while I do have a leak, Instruments shows only an occasional ~300 bytes (about once every 2-3 minutes with heavy use), but I'm still getting low memory errors and signal:9 killed:9 when it crashes.

Are there things that Allocations isn't showing me? (i.e. storyboard initialized views, or memory allocated on background threads)

How significant a problem is my small leak? I'm obviously working to stamp it out, but is it likely that this is just a red herring? Or could it be the cause of my crashes?

Comment: Are you certain your app is crashing b/c it is running out of memory?  Are you getting any crash report / error logs (you wouldn't get these if you ran out of memory btw)?

Comment: It was getting low memory messages, signal:9 killed:9, and killing off background processes, which some googling alluded to run-out-of-memory errors. However, I found [this article](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8316169/1095984) with [bbum's awesome HeapShot guide](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2010/10/17/when-is-a-leak-not-a-leak-using-heapshot-analysis-to-find-undesirable-memory-growth/), in the answers. That guide has certainly helped me find a couple leaks that weren't being caught by the Leaks instrument. It's a lot more stable already, so maybe that was it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some [HeapShot analysis](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2010/10/17/when-is-a-leak-not-a-leak-using-heapshot-analysis-to-find-undesirable-memory-growth/) (credit goes to bbum for the awesome walkthrough) and found two instances where I WAS in fact leaking memory, just in a way that wasn't being captured by the Leaks instrument.

App's been running steadily through a few more days of testing, so it seems alright now.